# Prevent storing duplicate dates in SQL Server from ASP.NET Core Web App

Tags: sql-server, date, asp.net-core, duplicates

Prevent storing Duplicate dates when the user selects dates from Asp Calendar control.

KEY:

1. lstAtHomeDates = listView
2. DatesTable     = SQL Server Database Table used to store selected dates

So far this is what I have done to implement this:

```
 void InsertDate()
        {


            try
            {
                SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection(conectString);
                if (cons.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cons.Open();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < lstAtHomeDates.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    string str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DatesTable WHERE convert(varchar, myDate, 23) = @theDate and empID = @employID";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cons);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", Convert.ToDateTime(lstAtHomeDates.Items[i]).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employID", Session["employId"]);
                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    cons.Close();

                    if(count > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<Script>alert('Dates already Submitted try another date...')</Script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cons.Open();

                        string stri = "INSERT INTO DatesTable(myDate, empID, labelID) VALUES(@thedates, @employID, 500 )";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(stri, cons);
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thedates", lstAtHomeDates.Items[i]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employID", Session["employId"]);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Response.Write("<Script>alert('working from home dates added!!...');</Script>");
                    }

                    ClearList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<Script>alert('Error Message: " + ex.Message + "');</Script>");
            }

        }
```

I get this error from my catch clause when I try to click on the Save button while I was debugging

> ex.Message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Does this mean the date from the listview was not converted and therefore unable to match the dates from the front end and back end? Please help.

Comment: Why do you mix parametrisation and injection here? You parametrise `@theDates`, but then *inject* `Session["employId"]`. Also [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Unless you're building a single user system, you have to bear in mind that multiple users may be causing the same method to run at the same time. So if two users run your code, they both check that the date isn't in use. They both conclude it isn't. They both insert the same date. That's why, if you want uniqueness, you have to, *at the least*, enforce that down in the database with a constraint.

Comment: @Larnu I acknowledge your response but I use this session to track which employee selected the specific date so as to retrieve dates corresponding to the currently logged-in user I hope this makes sense but if I'm mistaken please tell me the correct way

Comment: I'm not asking why you're using `Session["employId"]`, I'm asking why you **inject** the value, when you clearly know that parametrisation exists (as you parametrise `@theDates`), and parametrisation is the *correct* thing to do. Why parametrise one value and inject another in the *same* statement?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  you mean maybe if I could create a constraint in my database or procedure to enforce this on my back end then read the procedure from my front end?

Comment: *@Larnu* I don't understand can you please tell me more, I'm a bit confused with this ... before I enter in a `for loop` i check for the existence of the selected date first then I check from the database it exists I print the message, if not I store the dates from the listview, what confusing me is where did I go wrong is the conversion side or somewhere else

Comment: Yes, first design your database so that, no matter how careless other code is, you cannot store data that's wrong. That's what a database `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is for.

Comment: `lstAtHomeDates.Items[i]` should be `lstAtHomeDates.Items[i].Value`. Side points: you are missing `using` on various objects. Why `ToString` a date only to convert it back again, why not leave it as a date in the first place? Instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` you can just do `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS...` and then check the rows affected. `WHERE convert(varchar, myDate, 23) = @theDate` what is the convert for, just compare the dates directly (or compare on date ranges)

Comment: Thank you very much I seen that I was missing `lstAtHomeDates.Items[i].Text` or `lstAtHomeDates.Item[i].Value` Thank you very much it now working fine i have posted the answer below on how i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue I was facing I the code below worked for me hoping it would help someone who faced the same issue or want to achieve the same thing as myself

```
 void InsertDates()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection(conectString);
                if (cons.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cons.Open();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < lstAtHomeDates.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    string str = "SELECT dateID FROM DatesTable WHERE convert(varchar, myDate, 111) = @theDate and empID = @employId";

                    String date = lstAtHomeDates.Items[i].Text;

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("", cons);

                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", date);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employID", Session["employId"]);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = str;
                    
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataset);

                    int count = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    cons.Close();

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<Script>alert('Dates already Submitted try another date...')</Script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cons.Open();

                        string stri = "INSERT INTO DatesTable(myDate, empID, labelID) VALUES(@thedates, @employID, 500 )";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stri, cons);

                        cmd = new SqlCommand(stri, cons);
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thedates", lstAtHomeDates.Items[i].Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employID", Session["employId"]);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Response.Write("<Script>alert('working from home dates added!!...');</Script>");
                    }

                    ClearList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<Script>alert('Error Message: " + ex.Message + "');</Script>");
            }

        }
```

I also referred to Microsoft Docs for implementation of the [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). Thank you to those who took their time to explain some things in my question and the issues I was facing.